# multiple async calls on page load

Tags: asynchronous, q, angular-promise

I want to implement a bunch of Ajax calls on a page load in my angular application, that are totally independent of each other. I want to make use of Javascript promises and $q library for this purpose since i need to work on the data returned by these calls.

What should be a way to do this? Is q.all a good fit?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the q.all() which is built-in or you can create an array of promises and manually resolve these at page load.

Note: For page load you can use the $**viewContentLoaded** event of the $**rootScope**.